# Get current post featured image ID

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is it possible to retreive the current post (inside the loop) featured image ID?

The reason why I want this is so I can do something like this...

```
<?php

$featuredID = //get the featured image id

echo do_shortcode('[gallery size="thumbnail" link="file" exclude="' . $featuredID . '"]');  

?>
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id):

```
$featuredID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
```

It returns `null` if there's not a featured image, so you may want to add a check for that.